# How are cross database joins performed in superset?

Tags: apache-superset

How are cross database joins performed in superset? For example, are the 2 datasources pulled into a pandas dataframe? or a sqlite / postgres db? then joined in memory? or do you have to provide a database instance for superset to perform operations like these?

Answer (score 0):

Superset provides the possibility of creating Virtual Datasets with custom SQL queries, so you need to have your datasources in tables in a database to perform the joins and create charts using the Virtual Datasets.

Comment: just to clarify, if I want to join a table from database A with another table from database B, how does superset do that? I'd like to know how superset implements that underneath the hood. I don't think users of superset necessarily need to know but I am curious

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe the SuperSet is an opensource equivalent to the ADO.Net DataSet from Microsoft. If so, then the selected data from both DB's are pulled into memory (data tables) using separate connections (because each connectionstring is going to be different) and then the operations are performed on the fly, in memory.

In that scenario, no external database would be required.